# Unable to run more than 2 webhooks on woocommerce simultaneously

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to use woocommerce webhooks to send product and order data to sync with salesforce. But i notice that at any point only 2 webhooks work, while the others don't. Changing the delivery URL and then testing the other logic works, but only 2 webhooks at anytime. and  I fail to understand why that is. Can anyone help to answer?

Comment: their code may be overriding ( conflicting ) with each other, try assign different priority to each of them

Comment: hi @TarunMahashwari, can you please tell me where should I add the priority? I don't see any function that accepts priority as a parameter. :| Please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

your hooks code may be overriding ( conflicting ) with each other, try assign different priority to each of them.

if you are using a filter hook, see [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/):

```
add_filter( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

and if you are using an action hook see [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )' for further details check this
```